# JSInterop compiled with webpack is undefined in blazor

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have a Blazor webassembly application, in which I am trying to include typescript/javascript code using JSInterop, which fails, when the js code is created by webpack during build.

When creating a simple `hello-world.js` file in my `wwwroot` with the following content:

```
export function showAlertSimple() {
    alert("hello world");
}
```

I can invoke it very easily using:

```cs
public class HelloWorld : JSModule
{
    public HelloWorld(IJSRuntime js) 
        : base(js, "./js/hello-world.js")
    {
    }

    public async Task ShowAlert() => await InvokeVoidAsync("showAlert");
}
```

If I try to do the same with a typescript file, which I created in a different place and then let it compile down to ES6 with webpack, put it into the same folder, blazor is unable to call the method:

./NpmJs/src/hello-world2.ts

```
export function showAlertFromWebPack() {
    alert("Hello World from webpack");
}
```

./NpmJs/webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    entry: {
        helloworld2: './src/hello-world2.ts',
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.ts?$/,
                use: 'ts-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
            },
        ],
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js'],
    },
    output: {
        filename: '[name].bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../../wwwroot/js'),
    },
    devtool: 'source-map'
};
```

```cs
public class HelloWorld2 : JSModule
{
    public HelloWorld2(IJSRuntime js)
        : base(js, "./js/helloworld2.bundle.js")
    {
    }

    public async Task ShowAlert() => await InvokeVoidAsync("showAlertFromWebPack");
}
```

This then throws the following exception in the browsers console:

```
crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
      Unhandled exception rendering component: Could not find 'showAlertFromWebPack' ('showAlertFromWebPack' was undefined).
      Error: Could not find 'showAlertFromWebPack' ('showAlertFromWebPack' was undefined).
```

The file itself is loaded correctly. I can see it in the source tab.

What am I missing here?

For completeness sake, here is the JSModule class, which I have shamelessly plugged from Steven Sanderson over at github.(https://github.com/SteveSandersonMS/AudioBrowser/blob/dd7a03d93b4de5e97efb333f1120792ee48c70ba/MediaFilesAPI/Util/JSModule.cs#L7)

```
public abstract class JSModule : IAsyncDisposable
{
    private readonly Task<IJSObjectReference> moduleTask;

    // On construction, we start loading the JS module
    protected JSModule(IJSRuntime js, string moduleUrl)
        => moduleTask = js.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("import", moduleUrl).AsTask();

    // Methods for invoking exports from the module
    protected async ValueTask InvokeVoidAsync(string identifier, params object[]? args)
        => await (await moduleTask).InvokeVoidAsync(identifier, args);
    protected async ValueTask<T> InvokeAsync<T>(string identifier, params object[]? args)
        => await (await moduleTask).InvokeAsync<T>(identifier, args);

    // On disposal, we release the JS module
    public async ValueTask DisposeAsync()
        => await (await moduleTask).DisposeAsync();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found 2 working solutions. One using webpack, the other by ditching webpack and replacing it by [vitejs](https://vitejs.dev).

Using **webpack** we need to enable `experiments.outputModule` (https://webpack.js.org/configuration/experiments/#experimentsoutputmodule) and set `output.library.type` to `module` (https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputlibrarytype):

The final config would then look like this:

```js
module.exports = {
    entry: {
        helloworld2: './src/hello-world2.ts',
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.ts?$/,
                use: 'ts-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
            },
        ],
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js'],
    },
    output: {
        filename: '[name].bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../../wwwroot/js'),
        library: {
            type: "module",
        },
    },
    experiments: {
       outputModule: true
    },
    devtool: 'source-map'
};
```

Using **vitejs** the vite.config.js, the config would looke like this:

```js
import * as path from 'path';
import { defineConfig } from "vite";

export default defineConfig({
   appType: 'mpa',
   build: {
      target: 'esnext',
      outDir: '../wwwroot/js',
      lib: {
         entry: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/index.ts'),
         name: "YourPackageName",
         fileName: (format) => `your-package-name.${format}.js`,
      },
   }
});
```

Vite itself will then produce 2 files:

- `your-package-name.es.js`
- `your-package-name.umd.js`

You need to link / use the es file inside blazor and you're good to go.

Comment: For me...I tried everything but couldn't get Webpack to produce an output that worked in Blazor JSInterop. Switching to Vite worked very well and was very easy. Thank you for the suggestion!