# Using Vite or webpack as bundler in Blazor WASM with JSInterop

Tags: blazor, openlayers, vite

How to use [Vite](https://vitejs.dev) or webpack in Blazor WASM with JSInterop?

I following this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74485893/jsinterop-compiled-with-webpack-is-undefined-in-blazor), but when I run blazor WASM, then not working js.
I use [openlayers](https://openlayers.org/)  library.

index.ts is the same as main.js in [OpenLayers](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/vector-esri.html) with added `import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css' import 'ol/ol.css'`

This code in vite.config.ts generating me ol.umd.js and ol.es.js and style.css.

1. I want style.css create to css folder, not js, but js files generate to js folder. How to do?
2. How to call with JSInterop any functions in index.ts (ol.es.js or ol.umd.js)?
3. Map don't show me. I have `<div id="map"></div>` and `<script src="js/ol.es.js"></script>` ` in index.html, but nothing doing.

When I use only index.js as module in example then some libraries not working, bucause openlayers using external library that not included.
Where is any tutorial or some examples for running Blazor with external js library with Vite as bundler and JSInterop?

vite.config.ts

```
import * as path from 'path';
import { defineConfig } from "vite";

export default defineConfig({
    appType: 'mpa',
    build: {
        target: 'esnext',
        outDir: '../wwwroot/js',
        lib: {
            entry: path.resolve(__dirname, './index.ts'),
            name: "OpenLayers",
            fileName: (format) => `ol.${format}.js`,
        },
    }
});
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "npm_packages",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "vite build"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "vite": "4.4.9"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "ol": "7.5.1",
    "bootstrap": "5.3.1"
  }
}
```